# C# Конвертировать буффер byte* в System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, графика, bitmap

У меня есть буфер, содержимое буффера blue green red alpha blue green red alpha blue ..... из этого буффера (в коде - buffer) нужно получить Bitmap. Вроде делаю всё правильно но получаю пустой Bitmap.

```
public Bitmap ConvertToNewBitmap()
    {
        Bitmap x = new Bitmap(Width,Height,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, x.Size);
        BitmapData bmpData = x.LockBits(rect,ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        
        byte* buff2 = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            buff2[i] = buffer[i];
        }
        
        x.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        
        return x;
    }
```

Получаю этот буффер с помощью обрезания текстуры, а начальная текстура получена из Bitmap

```
   public unsafe class Texture
    {   
        public byte* buffer;
        public Bitmap Source;
        public readonly string name;        
        public readonly int Width;
        public readonly int Height;
        public readonly int HalfWidth;
        public readonly int HalfHeight;
        public readonly int Stride;
        public Bitmap UnlockCopy;
        
        public int GetPixel(int x, int y)
        {
            return (y * Stride) + x * 4;
        }
public Texture(Texture Source, int X, int Y,int W, int H)
    {
        Width = W;
        Height = H;
        Stride = W*4;
        this.HalfWidth = W/2;
        this.HalfHeight = H/2;
        
        buffer = (byte*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(W*H*4);
        
        for(int i = X, n = 0; i < X+W; i++, n++)
            for(int j = Y, m = 0; j < Y+H; j++, m++)
        {
            int a = GetPixel(n,m);
            int b = Source.GetPixel(i,j);
            
            buffer[a] = Source.buffer[b];
            buffer[a+1] = Source.buffer[b+1];
            buffer[a+2] = Source.buffer[b+2];
            buffer[a+3] = Source.buffer[b+3];
        }
    }
    
    public void FreeBuffer()
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)buffer);
    }
    
    public Texture(string name, Bitmap bmp)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.Width = bmp.Width;
        this.Height = bmp.Height;
        this.HalfWidth = bmp.Width/2;
        this.HalfHeight = bmp.Height/2;
        
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Stride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
        Length = Stride * bmp.Height;   
        
        buffer = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;
        Source = bmp;
        
        Total += Length;            
    }
```

Comment: Bitmap x = new Bitmap(... - создаёт пустой битмап

Comment: ну я же туда данные из буффера копирую

Comment: BitmapData bmpData = x.LockBits(rect,ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        
        byte* buff2 = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            buff2[i] = buffer[i];
        }

Comment: А регионами скопировать не получается? Graphics grD = Graphics.FromImage(destBitmap); grD.DrawImage(srcBitmap, destRegion, srcRegion, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

Comment: Ответ был удалён из-за отсутствия реакции на него.

Comment: Я давно нашёл ошибку, дело было в том, что Length был = 0

Answer (score 0):

Я давно нашёл ошибку, дело было в том, что Length был = 0